# Why are coordinate processes continuous semi-martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

We have the following setting.

Let $D$ be a bounded domain. We consider the Dirichlet form $(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F})$ on $L^2(D,dx)$ with $\mathscr{F}=H^1(D)$ and

$\mathscr{E}(u,v)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_D\sum^d_{i,j=1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}a^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}dx$

with the associated diffusion process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

If $\partial D$ and $a=(a^{ij})$ are smooth, it follows that the coordinate processes $X^i=(X^i_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are continuous semi-martingales.

Why does this last conclusion hold?

Comment: Write down an SDE which $X_t$ solves (up to the hitting time of the boundary).  The solution of an SDE is a semimartingale, under appropriate conditions which should be easy to verify here.  Then $X^i$ is a smooth function (projection onto $i$th coordinate) of the semimartingale $X$, hence itself a semimartingale.